# Finding a user by their username#discrim

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Is it possible to get someone's user ID who you know their username and discrim, but is not in a mutual server with you?

Thanks.

Comment: No, it's not possible, discord API [endpoint](https://github.com/discordapp/discord-api-docs/blob/master/docs/resources/User.md#DOCS_RESOURCES_USER/user-object) (which discord.py uses) only support fetching users by id. It's only possible if you're in a mutual server with them.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. It makes sense since this can easily be abused. Imagine all the spam bots if bots can see all discord users.

Below are two ways to get user info using `discord.py`, but note that they cannot be used as you ask.

[`client.get_user_info`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user_info) can be used to get user info even if you don't share a server, but it takes the unique ID as an argument.

[`server.get_member_named`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Server.get_member_named) returns the unique user ID and takes username plus the optional discriminator as input, but requires that you share server/guild with the user to work.