# Discord.py Is it possible to send a direct message to someone without them being in the server?

Tags: python-3.x, bots, discord.py

If I get a bot to send a direct message to someone, they have to be in the server for it to send. If they're not in server, I get this error: "discord.errors.Forbidden: FORBIDDEN (status code: 403): Cannot send messages to this user".

Is there any way to send a direct message to someone by inputting a userid and it not requiring them to be in the server?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to resolve a user you don't share a server with, even if you know their id.  I suspect Discord intentionally limits this functionality for privacy reasons.  It's likely that the Discord API, which `discord.py` is built on, doesn't allow this.

Comment: you could probably do this with a self-bot, but they are against the discord ToS and you could be banned for it

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848063/finding-a-user-by-their-usernamediscrim